# How to get max and second max value from a column when column is first sum in a table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this

[image]`

I need to find the maximum salary of department and the second maximum salary.

I have written this query

```
select sum(salary) 
from salary 
group by deptid
```

and I got this output:

[image]

Now I want to find the maximum salary and department so I wrote

```
select max(salary) 
from salary 
where in (select sum(salary) from salary)
```

But this does not work.

I need to find maximum and second maximum from the salary table group by `deptid` how to do that?

Comment: What would be the result if also D04 had 70000 salary?

Answer (score 2):

You might find that a limit query is enough here:

```sql
SELECT deptid, MAX(salary) AS max_salary
FROM salary
GROUP BY deptid
ORDER BY max_salary DESC
LIMIT 2;
```

More generally, we can use the `RANK` analytic function here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT deptid, MAX(salary) AS max_salary,
           RANK() OVER (ORDER BY MAX(salary) DESC) rnk
    FROM salary
    GROUP BY deptid
)

SELECT deptid, max_salary
FROM cte
WHERE rnk <= 2
ORDER BY max_salary DESC;
```